# ASP.NET Core Identity with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using .NET Core 3.0 Preview6.
We have an Intranet application with enabled Windows authentication which means that only valid AD users are allowed to use the application.
However, we like to run our own authentication backend with ASP.NET Identity, because it works "out-of-the-box". I just added a column to AspNetUsers table with the user's Windows login.

What I'd like to accomplish is that Windows users are automatically signed-in to the application with their Windows login.
I already created a custom Authentication middleware, please see code below:

```
public class AutoLoginMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AutoLoginMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<AutoLoginMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, UserService userService, UserManager<IntranetUser> userManager, 
        SignInManager<IntranetUser> signInManager)
    {
        if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(context.User))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User already signed in");
        }
        else
        {
            if (context.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity != null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"User with Windows Login {context.User.Identity.Name} needs to sign in");
                var windowsLogin = context.User.Identity.Name;


                var user = await userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.NormalizedWindowsLogin == windowsLogin.ToUpperInvariant());

                if (user != null)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true, "automatic");
                    _logger.LogInformation($"User with id {user.Id}, name {user.UserName} successfully signed in");

                    // Workaround
                    context.Items["IntranetUser"] = user;
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"User cannot be found in identity store.");
                    throw new System.InvalidOperationException($"user not found.");
                }
            }
        }

        // Pass the request to the next middleware
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

The doc says that `SignInManager.SignInAsync` creates a new `ClaimsIdentity` - but it seems that never happens - `HttpContext.User` always stays a `WindowsIdentity`. On every request the user is signed in again, the call to `signInManager.IsSignedIn()` always returns false.

My question now: is it generally a good idea to have automatic authentication in this way? What other ways do exists?

My next requirement is to have a custom `AuthorizationHandler`.
The problem here is that sometimes in the `HandleRequirementAsync` method the `AuthorizationHandlerContext.User.Identity` is a `WindowsIdentity` and then the call to `context.User.Identity.Name` raises the following Exception:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed.

Object name: 'SafeHandle'.

   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)

   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)

   at Interop.Advapi32.GetTokenInformation(SafeAccessTokenHandle TokenHandle, UInt32 TokenInformationClass, SafeLocalAllocHandle TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength, UInt32& ReturnLength)

   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetTokenInformation(SafeAccessTokenHandle tokenHandle, TokenInformationClass tokenInformationClass, Boolean nullOnInvalidParam)

   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_User()

   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.<GetName>b__51_0()

   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.<>c__DisplayClass67_0.<RunImpersonatedInternal>b__0(Object <p0>)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

My assumption now is that these both parts don't work well together. Sometimes it seems there is a timing issue - my custom `AuthorizationHandler` is called in between the call to `AutoLoginMiddleware`

Comment: I am getting "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to Invoke middlewares.AutoLoginMiddleware.  Do you know how to solve this?  The Startup has 
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseMiddleware<AutoLoginMiddleware>();

Comment: I guess you forgot to also register Identity framework:   `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()` should do the trick.

Comment: I did.  Here is my ConfigureServices()

services.AddIdentity<CustomIdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
         {
           options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

Comment: Then you'll have to add UserManager<CustomIdentityUser> as parameter to the AutoLoginMiddleware InvokeAsync method. From your error message it seems you mistakenly added the wrong UserManager<IdentityUser>

Comment: I'm working on a solution with a nearly same case and the idea of your AutoLoginMiddleware is exactly what i needed. But as soon as I add .AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>() the context.User.Identity never returns a WindowsIdentity - it is always from type ClaimsIdentity. Any hint what I'm missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is fixed now. It's been a bug in the preview releases. Now it's working like intended. Good luck!

**Update:** I'd like to post my working code for .NET Core 3.1 Final.

1. It's essential to register the custom login middleware after framework middlewares in `Configure`:

```cs
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseMiddleware<AutoLoginMiddleware>();
```

2. In the custom middleware, after signing in the user you must call `CreateUserPrincipalAsync` and save this principal to the `HttpContext.User` property.

   ```cs
   await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);
   context.User = await signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
   ```
3. For Blazor, we must use `AuthenticationStateProvider`. It has a property `User` which contains the `ClaimsPrincipal` from `HttpContext`. That's it.
4. You are now able to get the Identity user like follows:

   ```cs
   var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
   var intranetUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(authState.User);
   ```