# Is it possible to use the roles in .NET Core 6 Identity without using the login provided?

Tags: .net, identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to use Windows authentication and then use the Identity tables for managing users and roles. I don't need to have the login/register/password retrieval etc. I saw this question but it doesn't work for me.

[ASP.NET Core Identity with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877084/asp-net-core-identity-with-windows-authentication)

How can I use Windows authentication and then have the user populate the correct Identity objects? My last question was closed because it was too vague. I really just need to ask Sven, the OP of the article I linked, if he has the complete code in github so I can look at what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So, what's the question here? While your question might not be vague, it has the answer that you pointed to. If you follow that code and ran into problem, you need to include the code and specify the problem. "doesn't work for me" is not a question

Comment: The question is if you are using the windows authentication why you still need the identity role? The AD user contians its own role.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The linked answer is in .net core 3.1. I'm using .net core 6.  The first problem is that I don't know how to collapse the configuration " ConfigureServices() services.AddIdentity<CustomIdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => { options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; " into the program.cs file.

Comment: @Brando Shang - I have several different intranet applications.  I would like to have custom roles for each user for each application stored in a single database in the Identity tables.  Most users will be logged in with their domain account.  some of our applications need to use the machine mac address as the "login" username. I need roles for users and mac addresses.